# Estoy necesitando generar una alerta si le dan click a cualquiera de los botones sin antes ingresar un valor en el input

Tags: php, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3><p> Recibir por el metodo get dos numeros y realizar la operaciones de resta, suma, multiplicacion y division</p></h3>

<form action="ejercicio2.php" method="get">
Numero 1: <input type="number" name="numero1"><br><br>
Numero 2: <input type="number" name="numero2"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="sumar" value="Sumar">
<input type="submit" name="restar" value="Restar">
<input type="submit" name="multiplicar" value="Multiplicar">
<input type="submit" name="dividir" value="Dividir">
</form>
<?php
$outPut = "Nada posteado";

if ( isset($_GET['numero1']) && isset($_GET['numero2']) ) {
    $numero1 = $_GET['numero1'];
    $numero2 = $_GET['numero2'];
    if ( isset($_GET['sumar']) ) {
        $outPut = $numero1 + $numero2;
    } elseif ( isset($_GET['restar']) ) {
        $outPut = $numero1 - $numero2;
    } elseif ( isset($_GET['multiplicar']) ) {
        $outPut = $numero1 * $numero2;
    } elseif ( isset($_GET['dividir']) ) {
        $outPut = $numero1 / $numero2;
    }else {
         echo $outPut;
  }
}
echo "<br/>";
echo $outPut;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Tengo este pequeño codigo que estoy practicando para entender como funciona "if" lo que deseo hacer es que genere una alerta con el siguiente script =

Entonces si le dan click a cualquiera de los botones sin antes ingresar un valor en el input salte esta alerta

Comment: Los snippets solo son para HTML, CSS y Javascript. PHP no. Probablemente lo que quieres deba ser hecho del lado del cliente con javascript.

Comment: Coloca `required` en los inputs y saltará una alerta. Ejemplo: `<input type="number" name="numero1" required>`

Comment: `echo '<script>
alert("ingrese los valores para obtener el resultado");
window.history.go(-1);
</script>';
exit;` Este es el script que deseo agregar pero no se donde agregar para que valide esto o como generar el if para obtener este resultado

Comment: Debes ponerlos en los **else{}**, ya que cuando no se cumple la condición entrará al else y saltará la alerta

Comment: Esa es la cuestion no se como hacerlo ya intente mucho pero no me sale

Comment: Te han pedido que uses también js o solo con php?

Comment: Si Ricardo me piden incluir javascript en el php

Comment: Se puede hacer desde PHP (no recomendable), ya que el script se ejecutara al redirecionar  o enviar el formulario, lo mas conveniente es hacerlo con js desde el cliente, también te recomendaría usar Ajax para que te de el resultado sin necesidad de recargar la pagina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo desde las etiquetas HTML agregando el atributo **required**, con esto al tratar de enviar el formulario detectara si alguno de los **inputs** que cuentan con este atributo no tiene ningun valor, mostrara un tipo **alert** por defecto del navegador.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>
    <p> Recibir por el metodo get dos numeros y realizar la operaciones de resta, suma, multiplicacion y division</p>
  </h3>

  <form action="ejercicio2.php" method="get">
    Numero 1: <input type="number" name="numero1" required><br><br> Numero 2: <input type="number" name="numero2" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="sumar" value="Sumar">
    <input type="submit" name="restar" value="Restar">
    <input type="submit" name="multiplicar" value="Multiplicar">
    <input type="submit" name="dividir" value="Dividir">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Si necesitas hacerlo con javaScript indícalo y cambio la respuesta, lo recomendable es hacerlo desde el cliente. Como recomendación no mezcles *PHP con HTML o JS*, es muy mala practica.

Answer (score 0):

Te envió una mejor simplificación del código, si te sirve Marcala como una respuesta xfa

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body style="align-items: center; text-align: center;">
        <h3>
            <p> Recibir por el metodo get dos numeros y realizar la operaciones de resta, suma, multiplicacion y division</p>
        </h3>
        <div>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <label> Numero 1: </label>
                <input type="number" id="numero1" name="numero1" required value="<?php if (isset($_POST['numero1'])) {
                                                                                        echo $_POST['numero1'];
                                                                                    } ?>"><br><br>
                <label> Numero 2:</label>
                <input type="number" id="numero2" name="numero2" required value="<?php if (isset($_POST['numero2'])) {
                                                                                        echo $_POST['numero2'];
                                                                                    } ?>"><br><br>
                <label for="select">Selecciona una operación</label>
    
    
    
                <select class="form-select" name="operacion" id=" operacion">
                    <option value="suma">suma</option>
                    <option value="resta">resta</option>
                    <option value="multipliacion">multipliacion</option>
                    <option value="divicion">divicion</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="calcular" value="calcular" id="calcular">
            </form>
    
            <h2>Resultado de las operaciones</h2>
        </div>
    
        <?php
    
        $numero1 = $_POST['numero1'];
        $numero2 = $_POST['numero2'];
        $operacion = $_POST['operacion'];
    
        if (isset($_POST['calcular'])) {
            switch ($operacion) {
                case 'suma':
                    $resultado = $numero1 + $numero2;
                    echo "La suma es " . $resultado;
                    break;
    
                case 'resta':
                    $resultado = $numero1 - $numero2;
                    echo "La resta es " . $resultado;
                    break;
    
                case 'multipliacion':
                    $resultado = $numero1 * $numero2;
                    echo "La multipliacion es " . $resultado;
                    break;
    
                case 'divicion':
                    $resultado = $numero1 / $numero2;
                    echo "La divicion es " . $resultado;
                    break;
    
                default:
                    # code...
                    break;
            }
        }
    
        ?>
    
    
    
    </body>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    
    </html>
```